# How to find rotated top, left of a rectangle given I have top, left and rotation angle

Tags: geometry, angle, rectangles

I think this is a simple problem but my Math/Geometry skills are not very good.

I am given the `top,left coordinates and the height & width of a rectangle` as input. Using this I plot the rectangle inside a larger one, using the top, left coordinates of the inside (smaller) rectangle as an offset from the top, left of the larger rectangle.

Let the unit of measurement be pixels. So if the top,left coordinates are (0,0) for the lower rectangle it means it is also starting at the same exact coordinate as the larger one. I then draw them till height,width pixels. If the coordinates are (100,50) then it means that smaller rectangle starts 100px to the right and 50px lower to the top of the top, left of the larger rectangle, etc. I hope you get the point.

Now I am having an additional fifth input point which is the rotation angle for the smaller rectangle. So suppose I have as top, left values (10,5) and a rotation angle value of 45 for the smaller rectangle. This now means that my smaller rectangle should now be rotated at clockwise 45 degress, whereby the rectangle now will now no longer be parallel to the ground. How to I calculate the necessary top, left coordinate in order to draw this rotated rectangle?

Comment: Which is the center point for the rotation? The top left corner of the small rectangle, the (0,0) point...?

Comment: The rectangle will be rotated based on its middle point...hope this answers your question.

Comment: Are you moving the smaller rectangle to a new place such that it still fits inside the larger rectangle but is now rotated? If so does the smaller rectangle have to still touch the edges of the larger rectangle?

Comment: Regarding rotations, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094016/trig-issue-calculate-triangle-height-for-overlapping-rectangles/2094124#2094124) should help.

Comment: Have you tried searching this site or looking through the related problems at right? Rotating rectangles comes up quite frequently here.

Comment: @SonnyDaSilva-Peters: I do not mind it going out of the larger rectangle. It is just blindly rotated based on the angle provided without worrying if the rectangle edges stay in or not.

Comment: Do you know the size of the larger rectangle and thereby the smaller rectangle? if you do you can use the rotation matrix with the center of your rectangle being the origin and get your new top left coordinate