# Calculating Wx and Hx from rotated rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to get Hx and Wx from a rotation. Given alpha=9º I need to get the height (Hx) and width (Wx) of the following image:

[image]

Note: We know the total width and height of the rectangle.

Comment: You can find a formula for the coordinates of one the rotated corners in the answer to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2094016/265466). You can find the others by symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to compute the numerics, but hopefully, you'll get the idea.

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be the corners of the original rectangle, starting from the top left corner going (unusually) clockwise. They have the respective coordinates $(-W/2. H/2), (W/2, H/2)$ and so on.

Let now $A'$, $B'$, $C'$, and $D'$ be the associated corners of the new rectangle after rotation of an angle $\theta$. The rotation matrix is $M_\theta = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{array}\right)$. Which means that $A' = M_\theta A$ and so on.

Let's have a look at the coordinates of the new points: 
$A' = M_\theta A = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c} -W\cos\theta - H \sin \theta \\ -W\sin \theta + H \cos \theta \end{array}\right)$. Similarly, $B' = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c} W\cos\theta - H \sin \theta \\ W\sin \theta + H \cos \theta \end{array}\right)$.

Let's now try to have the height of the point at the bottom of the top left white triangle. It will have coordinate $P = \left( \begin{array}{c} -W/2 \\ H/2-\text{Hx} \end{array} \right)$. 
To this end, consider the (running) point $P_t$ on the segment $[A', B']$. It has coordinates $P_t = A' + t(B'-A')$ for a certain $t \in (0,1)$, i.e. $P_t = \frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{c} W\cos \theta (2t-1) - H\sin\theta \\ -W\sin\theta + H \cos \theta (1-2t) \end{array} \right)$. 
By equality of the first component in $P_t = P$, you reach 
\begin{align}
W\cos \theta (2t-1) - H \sin \theta &= -W \\
\cos \theta (2t-1) &= -1 + \frac{H}{W}\sin \theta \\
t &= \frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\frac{1}{\cos \theta} + \frac{H}{W} \tan \theta \right)
\end{align}
Once you have $t$ from this formula, replace in the second component, et voila!

Comment: Note that the process is just the same for Wx. Also, though I have tried to write nicely on my paper, I am not guaranteeing that everything is correct to the minus sign -- let me know if you spot anything wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. So, It's supposed that once I get 't' I must sustitute it in the Pt formula to really get Hx?

Comment: Just corrected my answer -- sorry I had a foolish mistake in it. 

Plugging everything back in gives you 
$$
H_x = \frac{\sin \theta}{2} (W + \frac{H^2}{W})
$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. I have just calculated Hx for a angle of 9 degress and a W=250 and H=160. The result is 72,59. It represents more than 40% of the height. I think there's some bug.

Comment: Google gives me 27.56 google.com/search?q=sin%289+deg%29%2F2*%28250%2B160*160%2F250%29 Which is realistic with the approximation $\sin \theta \approx \theta$  for small $\theta$ and assuming that the hypothenuse is close to the half width (which gives, as a very coarse first order approximation 19.625) 
Or using the coarse approximation I had given before, via $W\tan \theta / 2 \approx H_x$.

Comment: Yes!! I made a mistake due to my calculator was by default in radians instead of degress. One more question, The above formula can be used for Wx merely changing W -> H and viceversa?

Comment: Yes. That should do the trick :) 
But as a practice, you can also try to recover these formulas, replacing A with B, and B with C (W/2. -H/2). You should arrive to the same formula.